# Multiple Segue from single UIButton which is changing due to ImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, segue

In main view controller there is an **ImageView** in the middle, UIButton in the bottom. The **ImageView** has tap gesture and when you tap it the image changes from Credits to Scenes images and the  Button title changes to **Credits Button** from **Scenes Button**. Those buttons must have segues to its own. So I want to create segues to **CreditsController** and **ScenesController** from that button. I couldn't create double segue from the storyboard.

I appreciate for any help and I can provide more information if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do "double segues" from a storyboard. There are two methods:

1. Ctrl-drag from the view controller symbol (the yellow one) to the destination view controller. Name the segue and call it (in the button handler or the gesture recognizer handler) with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.
2. Use separate buttons with title or image and set their `hidden` property as appropriate. Now you can ctrl-drag from the buttons to the destination view controller.

Comment: I will use the first one i think, because on my homework it is necessary to do with one button. Thank you so much!